# Count number of values within a range in a specific column

Tags: linux, text-processing, numeric-data

I have to count the number of values that are between 0 and 0.05 in column 11 of a dataset. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '($11>0 && $11<0.05){ ++count } END{ print count }' file
```